# How can I Input variable length string and output user defined length string?

Tags: c, string, hash

As some function like MD5 can take input of variable length string/byte-array, and output a fixed length value byte-array(i.e. In hex). I want some standard function that can input variable length string/byte-array and output a user defined length byte-array/string.
Is there any way to do so?

Comment: " Is there any way to do so?" Yes. In C strings are zero-terminated char arrays so it's easy to input a string of any length and return a string of any length. Just use `char*` for both and use dynamic allocation (`malloc`) to get memory for the return string.

Comment: If your question is asking for a hash function, then no, the C standard does not defein such functionality. You would need to fall back using external libraries or home grown code.

Comment: It isn't very clear what you're after. MD5 logically takes in a byte array—not necessarily a string—of any length and generates a 16-byte value (frequently encoded as 32 hex digits). Do you want to be able to specify both the input length (as with MD5) and specify the output length? What range of output lengths? Should the output be related somehow to the input? Do you want to use MD5 for up to 16 bytes (128 bits), then SHA1 from 17 to 20 bytes, SHA2-256 for 21 to 32 bytes, and SHA3-512 for 33 to 64 bytes (512 bits), etc? Such things are possible; whether they're a good idea is another matter.

Comment: i want like 1st input value of fixed length 6 i,e; "abcdef" and output string of user defined length, i,e; 128 bits. But in 2nd attempt i want same input length 6 i,e; "123ttf" and output some other length string (i,e 192 bits) from same function and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use extendable-output function(XOF) like SHAKE-128/SHAKE-256 defined in [NIST.FIPS-202](http://dx.doi.org/10.6028/NIST.FIPS.202).

In **c** you can implememnt **SHAKE-128** and can call in main() as:

```
shake128(0,shake_key,&shake_context);        //set key for shake
shake128(output_len, output_var, &shake_context) //hash function
```

Instead of creating a fixed-length digest (e.g. like MD5/SHA-2/256), it can produce outputs of any desidered length.

Comment: You can also try, 1st: md5(input_string), and then 2nd:shake128(md5_inputstring). This help you to keep always a fixed length input to shake128().

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's quite possible. Here is a template:

```
char *foo(const char *input, size_t output_length) {
    size_t input_length = strlen(input);
    char *ret = malloc(input_length + 1);
    if(!ret) 
        return NULL;

    /* Custom code here. Maybe something like this:
       for(size_t i; i<input_length; i++) {
           ret[i] = 
    */

    return ret;
}
```